# sharing class object to another socket only shares the object and results in function not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

So I have my own class in node.js , called - `test.js` in which there's a function called `bla()`

In my node1, I do the following.

```js
const t = new test();
io.emit('event', t);
```

and on my node2,

```js
socket.on('event', (t) => {
  console.log(t); // this prints the correct output which means sockets work fine.
  const aha = t.bla(); // this results in a function not found.
})
```

Looks like an object is getting shared, but not the actual instance . How do I fix this?